# Add image to an email from a local path

Tags: javascript, string, spring, thymeleaf, email-attachments

How can I add using the path that is inside a server, an image to be included in an e-mail that is sent via Spring with Thymeleaf?

This is my controller:

```js
final Map<String, String> inlineResources = new HashMap<String, String>();
Set<String> folderPath = new TreeSet<>();
  for (File file : files) {

   ... some previous code ()   
   
   StringBuilder pathFile = new StringBuilder(config.getFileCachePath());
   pathFile.append("/").append(folder.getId()).append("/").append(certificateFile.getName());
   folderPath.add(pathCertificate);
  }
    
    String folderPathString = StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(folderPath);
    
    inlineResources.put("img1", "/template/email/img/myImg.png");
    inlineResources.put("file", "folderPath");
```

And this my html email:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title th:remove="all">Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;">
     
     <p>TEXT EMAIL</p>
     <img style="max-width: 100%;" th:src="'cid:img1'" />
     <img style="max-width: 100%;" th:src="'cid:file'" />
    </body>
</html>
```

In this case img1 load correct, while th:src="'cid:file'" is not load.

And in folderPath.add(pathCertificate); i have this error:

The method add(String) in the type Set is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuilder)

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Maybe `file` is not public?

Comment: Looks like you try to put a StringBuilder to the set instead of a String. Call toString() method on the StringBuilder.

Comment: You pathCertificate is of type StringBuilder. Tried this `folderPath.add(pathCertificate.toString());` ?

Comment: I try to use folderPath.add(pathCertificate.toString()); but i have the same problem: 

Error while sending email message to '[mail@mail.com]'
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [srv/dev/contents/fileCache/134/file.jpg] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: I use the same path on my server [srv/dev/contents/photo/134/file.jpg] to load on e.g. in Home may photo: <img th:src="@{/contents/images/photo/134/file.jpg}">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is to use "file:":

```
String pathImg = certificateFile.toString().replace('\\', '/'); inlineResources.put("img", "file:"+pathImg);
```